# Find the greatest and the least values of the function $f(x)=\sin x\sin2x$ on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Find the greatest and the least values of the function $f(x)=\sin x\sin2x$ on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$.

The solution presented is as follows:

> Represent the function $y=f(x)=\sin x\sin 2x$ in the form $y=\frac{\cos x-\cos 3x}{2},$ whence it is seen that the function is an even one and has a period $2\pi.$ Hence, it is sufficient to seek the greatest and the least values among the extrema on the interval $[0, \pi].$ Find the derivative $y'=\frac12(3\sin {3x}-\sin x)$ In $[0,\pi]$ the derivative vanishes at the points $x_1=0,x_2=\arccos \frac {1}{\sqrt{3}},x_3=\arccos(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}),x_4=\pi.$ Compute the values of the function at these points: $y(0)=y(\pi)=0,y[\arccos(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})]=\pm\frac {4}{3\sqrt{3}}.$ Hence, the least value of the function in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ is equal to $-\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}$ and $\frac{4}{3\sqrt 3}.$

However, in the above solution, I dont get, how do they assert "Hence, it is sufficient to seek the greatest and the least values among the extrema on the interval $[0, \pi].$" ? The function is periodic and even but that only leads us to investigate it in the interval $[0, 2\pi].$ I don't get why investigating this function at $[0, \pi]$ is sufficient. I am not quite getting it.

Comment: As the function is even, when you have all solutions in $[0,\pi]$ is suffices to mirror them to get all solutions in a period.

Answer (score 2):

It is also periodic on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and so by eveness the solutions are symmetric along $0$ and so we can focus on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative resolution:**

By direct differentiation, we have to solve

$$\sin(2x)\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(2x)=0$$

or

$$2\sin(x)(3\cos^2(x)-1)=0.$$

When $\sin(x)=0$, the function equals $0$. When $3\cos^2(x)-1=0$, the function $\sin(x)\sin(2x)=2(1-\cos^2(x))\cos(x)$ equals one of $\pm\dfrac4{3\sqrt3}$.